# Remote Control for Sony NEX 5 with bracketed images

Tags: hdr, remote, sony-nex, bracketing

Most remote controls that I've tried with my Sony NEX 5t only allow for a single shot shutter action. I'd like to be able to show bracketed images with a remote control. Are there options on the market for a remote control with this capability?

Comment: How does this function normally operate? do you need to hold down the shutter button?

Answer (score 1):

The [Sony RMTDSLR2 remote](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0097DFRMC) states in the description (bolding mine):

> Features
>
> Video record start/stop.
>
> Remote shutter release control.
>
> Single Shot, **Burst**, 2 Second Self Timer control.
>
> Slideshow Playback Control.

In the compatible models it lists the NEX 5T:

> Compatible Models
>
> ILCA-99M2; ILCA-77M2; ILCA-77M2M; ILCA-77M2Q; SLT-A99;
>
> SLT-A99V; ILCE-7RM3; ILCE-9; ILCE-6500; ILCE-6300; ILCE-6300L;
>
> ILCE-7SM2; ILCE-7RM2; ILCE-7M2; ILCE-7M2K; ILCE-7S; ILCE-6000;
>
> ILCE-6000L; ILCE-6000Y; ILCE-7; ILCE-7K; ILCE-7R; **NEX-5T**;
>
> NEX-5TL; NEX-5R; NEX-6.
>
> Limited functionality of remote with the following models:
>
> NEX-5N; NEX-5NK; NEX-7; NEX-7K.

From your problem description it seems this remote would do what you want.
If it works, please let us know by accepting this answer.